# macOS Big Sur - An error occured while installing the selected updates

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur

Why my update to Big Sur keeps failing?

[image]
[image]

I have tried everything: recovery mode, stable wifi, restart... and it still appears.

Comment: I know that the question is to be removed, but [multiple people reporting this](https://twitter.com/tonyarnold/status/1326992742208081920?s=21)

Comment: I got the same error. No idea why. I've got a 2018 Macbook pro, plenty of ram and disk space. :(

Comment: You can also [monitor the outage here](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/)

Comment: Download below package and upgrade the Big Sur http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/50/49/001-79699-A_93OMDU5KFG/dkjnjkq9eax1n2wpf8rik5agns2z43ikqu/InstallAssistant.pkg

Comment: Above is the same package used by macOS to upgrade Big Sure

Comment: In my case, I fixed it installing some pending security updates. Then, I was able to complete the installation.